# How to rewrite on a CATextlayer?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, calayer, catextlayer

I am using CATextLayer for my custom calendar design. I am using CAlayer to draw numbers for each month. But when i move to next month by pressing next button the dates are overlapping.I tried removing sublayers but no use. Please help me out..

[image: Initial Calendar]

But when i move to December month . The dates overlaps

[image]

The code i used is:

```
 [date sizeWithAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:10.0] }];
            self.mainLayer = [self layer];
            [self.mainLayer setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];

            self.messageLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
            [self.messageLayer setForegroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
            [self.messageLayer setContentsScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
            [self.messageLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(targetX+2, targetY+10, kVRGCalendarViewDayWidth, kVRGCalendarViewDayHeight)];
            [self.messageLayer setString:date];



            self.messageLayer.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef)@"HelveticaNeue-Bold";
            messageLayer.fontSize = 10;
            messageLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
            [mainLayer addSublayer:messageLayer];

           [mainLayer setShouldRasterize:YES];
```